# java communication between 2 JFrames

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I'm getting an AWT-EventQueue-0 Null Pointer Exception in the below code and I can't get to fix it.

I want to have a main frame, from which by pressing a button 
I open a second frame, where I have the option to create new players,
which would show up in the main frame.
I passed the references to the constructors, but I still keep getting the error.

I would be very happy for some help, thanks!

```
public class Main { 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {                     
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                       new App();
                 }
          });
   }
}

public class App extends JFrame {
   private MainPanel mainPanel;
   private SecondPanel secondPanel;

   public App() {
          setVisible(true);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setSize(800, 600);

          secondPanel = new SecondPanel(mainPanel);
          mainPanel = new MainPanel(secondPanel);

          add(mainPanel);
   }

}

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
   private JTextArea textArea;
   private JScrollPane scrollPane;
   private JButton options;          


   public MainPanel(SecondPanel secondPanel) {
          textArea = new JTextArea();
          textArea.setColumns(20);
          textArea.setRows(5);
          textArea.setSize(300, 300);
          textArea.setVisible(true);
          textArea.setEditable(false);

          scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
          scrollPane.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));


          options = new JButton("Options");
          options.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                      secondPanel.setVisible(true);
                 }
          });


          add(scrollPane);
          add(options);

   }


   public JTextArea getTextArea() {
          return textArea;
   }


   public void setTextArea(JTextArea textArea) {
          this.textArea = textArea;
   }
}

public class SecondPanel extends JFrame {
   private JButton create, remove;
   private JPanel panel;

   public SecondPanel(MainPanel mainPanel) {
          setVisible(false);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setSize(400, 400);

          panel = new JPanel();
          panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

          create = new JButton("create");
          create.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                      mainPanel.getTextArea().append("New Player Created");

                 }
          });

          remove = new JButton("remove");
          remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                       mp.getTextArea().setText("Player removed");
                 }
          });

          add(panel);

          panel.add(create, BorderLayout.EAST);
          panel.add(remove, BorderLayout.WEST);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it has to be "null", because you don't initialise your MainPanel before you hand it over to the secondPanel.

Instead, make an own method for setting the MainPanel on the secondPanel and to set the secondPanel on the MainPanel.

I see that you need the secondPanel for instance in your constructor to set an ActionListener. Do that in your "setSecondPanel(SecondPanel sPanel)"-Method which, as I mentioned before, you should create.